# Different layout for Horayos

Tags: masechet-horayot

Horayos seems to be laid out differently from the usual--with Rashi (or what is called Rashi, even if perhaps not by him) on both sides, Tosafos at the bottom and dedicated space for Rabbeinu Chananel on every daf. Does anybody know why? Thanks.

Comment: Jon Glixon, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks very much for bringing your question here! I hope you'll stick around, find other information of interest  and keep asking and answering.

Comment: Could it be because there's a lot of Rashi on Horayos, so they have to put Tosfos on the bottom because Rashi takes up so much room?

Comment: @ezra While I agree with your point, I would actually say it the other way around: not that there's specifically a lot of Rashi, just that there's very little Tosfos! If I'm not mistaken, there are plenty of Daf in that Mesechta (and I use the term 'plenty' loosely, since there aren't that many Daf to begin with :P ) that don't have Tosfos at all. As an aside, I'm sure I've seen a handful of other places where Rashi is on both sides and no Tosfos, so I think the answer to this question is: it's simply a publishing/stylistic decision based on what they have to print.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because when the pagination of the Talmud was standardized, no Tosafot were printed on the page for Horayot.

Here's the [first page](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22196&st=&pgnum=4) of the Venice edition of the Horayot that standardized the pagination of the Talmud:
[image]

As you can see, it has Rashi but no Tosafot.

The Tosafot were added in the [Vilna edition](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14303&st=&pgnum=218) with this note to explain their provenance: They were found in a manuscript and had already been printed with Hagahot Asheri on Sukka.

[image]

Since the form of the page had already been standardized, they were added outside the page along with the other things added in the Vilna edition (such as Rabbeinu Chanan'el, which was also printed for the first time in the Vilna edition).